# How does jump above works in AT&T assembly format

Tags: assembly, x86, att

if in x86-64 AT&T version (not Intel), I guess in only changes the direction of source and destination, but anyway if I type:

```
cmp %bx,%ax
ja label
```

Assuming all numbers are unsigned, what exactly means ja? Jump if a>b or b>a? Because it is all about CF and ZF (meaning no carry/borrow, and nonzero)?????

Comment: Intel syntax doesn't change around the `ja` / `jbe` mnemonics, just the order for multi-operand instructions like `cmp`, so yes, the semantic meaning ("above") is backwards.

Answer (score 2):

It does exactly the same thing that

```
cmp ax, bx
ja label
```

would do in Intel syntax.